# Applying mutate() and case_when() for each element in the dataframe using dplyr/tidyr?

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I originally have a dataset with size: 1652 rows, 50 columns, but the essence is the same in this example. The dataset is df, and I wish to end up with newdf. Does anybody know how to solve this using dplyr?

```
df <- cbind(c("HouseCar", "Car", "carmouse", "mouse", NA),
                  c("car", NA, "Mousehouse", "housevan", NA),
                   c(NA, "mousevan", "Carhouse", NA, "mouse"))

     df
     [,1]       [,2]         [,3]      
[1,] "HouseCar" "car"        NA        
[2,] "Car"      NA           "mousecar"
[3,] "carmouse" "Mousehouse" "Carhouse"
[4,] "mouse"    "house"      NA        
[5,] NA         NA           "mouse"
```

Desired output (there is a recoding hierarchy House > Vehicle (van, car) > Mouse):

```
> newdf
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "House"   "Vehicle" NA       
[2,] "Vehicle" NA        "Vehicle"
[3,] "Vehicle" "House"   "House"  
[4,] "Mouse"   "House"   NA       
[5,] NA        NA        "Mouse"
```

This is how I plan to do it, but I am wondering why this code won't work?

```
newdf <- df %>% 
  replace_na(., NA_character_) %>% 
  tolower(.) %>% 
  mutate_all(case_when(
    str_detect(., "house") ~ "House",
    str_detect(., "car|van") ~ "Vehicle",
    str_detect(., "mouse") ~ "Mouse",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

I keep getting this error message:

**Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :
no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'character')"**

Answer (score 3):

To do this `df` needs to be a tibble or dataframe object. The output of `cbind` is a matrix, which is in part why you are getting your error.

```
df <- data.frame(df)
names(df) <- paste0("col", 1:3)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(
    str_detect(.x, "house") ~ "House",
    str_detect(.x, "car|van") ~ "Vehicle",
    str_detect(.x, "mouse") ~ "Mouse",
    T ~ NA_character_
  )))
```

As of dplyr version 1.0.0 nearly all verbs with _at, _all, _if, etc. have been superseded by the `across` verb. You can check your version by using `packageVersion("dplyr")`.

**dplyr < 1.0.0**

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ case_when(
    str_detect(.x, "house") ~ "House",
    str_detect(.x, "car|van") ~ "Vehicle",
    str_detect(.x, "mouse") ~ "Mouse",
    T ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

---

**Output**

```
     col1    col2    col3
1    <NA> Vehicle    <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA> Vehicle
3 Vehicle   House   House
4   Mouse   House    <NA>
5    <NA>    <NA>   Mouse
```

---

**Update**

To ignore case you can do a few things:

1. As you mentioned in your comments you can change the case to everything before applying your function:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), tolower)) # pipe to rest of code
```

2. You can use `stringr::regex` to ignore case on your `str_detect`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(
    str_detect(.x, regex("house", ignore_case = T)) ~ "House",
    str_detect(.x, regex("car|van", ignore_case = T)) ~ "Vehicle",
    str_detect(.x, regex("mouse", ignore_case = T)) ~ "Mouse",
    T ~ NA_character_
  )))
```

3. The built in function `grepl` does the same thing:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(
    grepl("house", .x, ignore.case = T) ~ "House",
    grepl("car|van", .x, ignore.case = T) ~ "Vehicle",
    grepl("mouse", .x, ignore.case = T) ~ "Mouse",
    T ~ NA_character_
  )))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know how we may make the string-matching non-sensitive to capital letters?

Comment: I have been trying to use mutate(across(tolower(.))), but end up with:  Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") :  object 'list(x1 = c("gange_t-bane", "", "bil (kjørte selv)", "gange_buss", "sykkel", "bil (kjørte selv)"))' of mode 'function' was not found.    The text in foreign language is equivalent with "house, mouse, van/car" in the example.

Comment: The first argument to `across` is which columns you want to apply your function over using [tidyselect](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) syntax. That's why in my code I used `everything()`, which applies the `case_when` over all columns.